# Is it possible to hide or disable chat on Google Drive for all the users that are sharing the document?

Tags: google-drive, account-management, chat, permissions

I need to disable the chat on my Google Drive’s shared documents, as I work with people around the world who need privacy. As I discovered, you have the chance to disable it in your own account, but I need to hide/disable for every user that shares my document. It's possible?

Comment: What type of Google accounts you and your collaborators are using? a) consumer accounts (free) b) Google Apps for Work accounts

Answer (score 1):

G Suite administrators can turn off chat inside Docs, Sheets, and Slides by turning off Google Hangouts. See Turn Hangouts on or off for users.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to turn it off...for now...